# How to show banner ads in fragment Revmob?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, revmob

I would like to show banners in a fragment instead of an activity, how can I do this?

My Fragment:

Variables:

```
RevMob revmob;
Activity currentActivity;
Functions:
```

My Code:

```
public void startRevMobSession(){
currentActivity = this;
revmob = RevMob.startWithListener(currentActivity, new RevMobAdsListener() {
    @Override public void onRevMobSessionStarted() {loadBanner();}
    @Override public void onRevMobSessionNotStarted(String message) {}});
}

public void loadBanner() {
revmob.showBanner(currentActivity, Gravity.BOTTOM, null, new RevMobAdsListener() {
    @Override public void onRevMobAdReceived() {}
    @Override public void onRevMobAdNotReceived(String message) {}
    @Override public void onRevMobAdDismissed() {}
    @Override public void onRevMobAdClicked() {}
    @Override public void onRevMobAdDisplayed() {}});
}
```

onCreate:

```
startRevMobSession();
```

It's working when I'm using it in an activity, but I would like to use it in a fragment. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fragment you should do:

```
currentActivity = getActivity();
```

instead of

```
currentActivity = this;
```

That's the only difference, it should all work properly then.

Comment: It does show the banner now, but it does not have a different banner in each fragment. I'm using a tablayout with 5 tabs (so 5 fragments) and I would like each fragment to have a banner ad.